# Impedance matching to minimize VSWR

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance, reflection

I was trying to determine what the impact of impedance mismatching would be to an RF output and I came across this.

About half way down the page, the author makes this claim.

> In general, if the VSWR is under 2 the antenna match is considered very good and little would be gained by impedance matching

[VSWR (Voltage Standing Wave Ratio)](http://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/vswr.php)

Using the following expressions

$$ \Gamma =\cfrac{Z_L - Z_0}{Z_L + Z_0} $$
$$ VSWR = \cfrac{1 + | \Gamma| }{1 - |\Gamma|}$$

If my \$Z_L\$ is 50 \$\Omega\$, then in order to get VSWR < 2, my \$Z_0\$ would be either approach 25\$\Omega\$ or approach 100\$\Omega\$.

If the above is true, then why do people go to such lengths get their \$Z_o\$  engineered correctly or is the author incorrect ?

Comment: Do you mean if your \$Z_L = 50\Omega\$? Also note that "under 2" is not the same as "equals 2."

Comment: Yes, \$Z_L\$ will update now.

Comment: the Bit  Error Rate will be a strong function of VSWR.